# In tensorflow, what is the easiest way to count the elements in a tensor that are larger than a threshold?

Tags: tensorflow

e.g. giving a `m x n` tensor, I'm trying to find the elements that are bigger than a threshold.

It seems this can be done with `tf.greater` but it seems I need to construct a `m x n` tensor of that threshold?

Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: Elements as in? What shape are these elements you refer to?

Comment: Give some concrete example for people to understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to *count* the number of elements greater than a threshold:

```py
x = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]])
threshold = 4
elements_gt = tf.math.greater(x,threshold)
num_elements_gt = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.cast(elements_gt, tf.int32))
print(num_elements_gt)
```

You can use `tf.greater`, `tf.greater_equal`, `tf.less`, `tf.less_equal` as the filter when computing `elements_gt`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't searched for long:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x= tf.constant([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], dtype=tf.float32)
out=  tf.greater(x, 2.5)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(out))
```

gives:

> [[False False False]  [ True  True  True]]

Comment: thanks, you r right, i did do exactly this but the i misunderstood the error. [i think i read tf.greater need construct a same tensor for comparing from somewhere ]. I fixed that error by using tf.cast and everything works fine now.